# Calling a method after a date is selected

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I have a separate datepicker class that i call from inside my MainActivity.

```
public void showDateDialog(View v){
        DateDialog dialog= new DateDialog(findViewById(R.id.textView));
        FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");
```

What i would like to do is to, after the user has chosen their date and pressed ok, check if the selected date has a string assigned to it in SharedPreferences. I have created a method for this inside my MainActivity:

```
public void checkHours(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("savedHours", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String date = textView.getText().toString();

    if (sharedPref.contains(date)) {
        textView2.setText(sharedPref.getString(date, ""));
    }
}
```

The date string is the one i have from the DatePicker. I am trying to call this from inside my DateDialog class:

```
 public void onDateSet (DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        String date=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
        textView.setText(date);
    MainActivity.checkHours();
}
```

But i am getting the error "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". Is there any way i can use checkHours() from inside DateDialog, if not how else can i do it?

DateDialog class:

```
public class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {

TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
public DateDialog(View view){
    textView=(TextView)view;
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
}
public void onDateSet (DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        String date=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
        textView.setText(date);
    MainActivity.checkHours();
}
```

}

Comment: The `onDateSet` method needs use a reference to the `Activity` instance. Please can you include code for the class containing this method.

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: If possible can you include the code for the `DateDialog` class?

Comment: Ok, I have inserted it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the method `checkHours` on an instance of `MainActivity`. You can get an instance by invoking `getActivity()` (as this class extends `Fragment`) and casting to `MainActivity`. (I am assuming that the `Fragment` is associated with `MainActivity`).

Replace

```
MainActivity.checkHours();
```

with

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).checkHours();
```

Comment: No problem. It took ages to realise what to do (I've never used Fragments) but I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your DateDialog class needs to either get a hold of the exact activity reference to call back into when the date is known, or it needs to receive some interface object that it can call into, whose implementation will then go and make changes in the Activity.

It's usually better to use the abstraction of an interface for stuff like this.